# reordering for FFT in python

Tags: python, fft

I'm new to python and FFT. I have taken a small task in Python to find the shuffling order for a given number of datapoints.

My objective is to have an output like below for N datapoints. Here `N=8`, so we have 3 sets:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The code I tried is below. Could someone help me where I'm wrong and suggest modifications to the code to produce the desired output.

```
le=8
steps=int(math.ceil(math.log(le,2)))

pos2=[]
m=0
for k in range(0,steps):
    x=2**k
    #print x
    pos1=[]    
    for i in range(0,le):
        if m<x:
            pos1.append(0)
            m=m+1
        else:
            pos1.append(1)
            m=0
    pos2.append(pos1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately get back to appending `0`s after appending only one `1`. Here is a working version with slightly different logic:

```
import math

le = 8
steps = int(math.ceil(math.log(le, 2)))

pos2 = []
for k in range(0, steps):
    x = 2**k
    pos1 = []
    while len(pos1) < le:
        for i in range(0, x):
            pos1.append(0)
        for i in range(0, x):
            pos1.append(1)
    pos2.append(pos1)
    print pos1
```

this will print

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and here is a one-liner for you to examine:

```
import math
le = 8

pos2 = [[(i // 2**k) % 2 for i in range(le)] for k in range(int(math.ceil(math.log(le, 2))))]

print pos2
```

Comment: Thanks. You're awesome.

Comment: @Vijaynitk You're welcome. I also included a 1-liner version if you are interested.

Comment: The one liner version looks complicated for me (new bee). I could understand the earlier lengthier version much easier. It is simple and clear. Thanks buddy.